# Regex strip all html tags excluding <br> & <a class='user'></a>

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

I am relatively new to regex but my aim is to strip all html tags from a string excluding `<br>`s and `<a>` tags with the class='user'. I want to user this regex to clean unwanted html garbage from contentedittable fields.

Hope one of you regex masters can help...

**Here is an example to test on:** http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2tpai

I think I'm close, but the closing tag of the a class='user' is currently still being selected as garbage when it is required.

Comment: Don't roll your own. This is important and nontrivial stuff. It has been done a zillion times. Re-use it

Comment: *"I want to user this regex to clean unwanted html garbage from contentedittable fields."* If you're dealing with a contentEditable field, why not just walk the DOM tree? HTML is very difficult to parse with regular expressions. (In fact, I think it's technically impossible, but you can get a close approximation if you try really hard.)

Comment: Presumably, it's JUST the tags you want to strip, not their elements' content?

Comment: What about if the `class='user'` isn't the _first_ attribute of the `<a>` tag?  What if the anchor tag has other tags inside it (such as an `<img>`)?  What if there are comments anywhere after your start tags, how will you know to skip over matches that appear inside them?  I don't think you're close at all - I don't mean to be critical, merely to emphasize the point in my answer that this is technically *impossible*, and even getting "good enough" for casual use is very, very hard.  There's undoubtedly even more issues that neither of us have considered.

Comment: @TJCrowder Ok if regex is the wrong choice could you give an example of how to clean the html in my example using javascript/jquery via DOM manipulation?

Comment: @sehe your comment isn't very helpful without examples. I have already searched for a solution and didn't find anything that matched my needs therefore I am posting a question here.

Comment: @pagewil: To be honest I don't have samples ready, but the warning stands: it is _not_ trivial and it _is_ important. I'll see what I can do for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this to you:

```
<(?!a class='user'|br|/a)[^>]+>
```

i.e., you keep in your html *all* the `</a>` tags, which should not bother much.

This is pretty hacky, but the regex engine will immediately skip a chunk of text starting with `<a class='user'` and start looking for the next `<`...

In general, in my experience with transforming html through regexes, I found out that the only way to go safely is splitting the process in several intermediate steps, like first dealing with the `<a class='user'..../a>`s, then with the rest, but I can't see an easy way to do that in your case without transforming the `<a class='user'..../a>` into something different as an intermediate step.

Comment: This expression works well except that it is ignoring all </a> tags not just the ones that match up with <a class='user'>

Answer (score 5):

Formally speaking you [can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not), because [HTML is not a regular language](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). See also [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) for some nightmare material.

Undoubtedly you can come up with some regexes that work in "most" situations, or "sensible" situations, but if you're sanitising user input via the regex this won't be sufficient.  It's not a million miles away from trying to substitute SQL parameters via elaborate textual replacement and escaping; no matter how clever you are, the correct answer is to use a different approach as *some* weakness will still exist.

In this case, that approach would be using an HTML parsing library to read the text, and then remove the `<br>` and `<a>` tags from the parsed DOM.  (This is much more robust then trying to remove a sequence of characters from the raw text, and probably creates more understandable source code too!).  In fact, since you're probably talking about JS in the client, you *already* have the DOM available, pre-parsed by the browser, so this would be a simple operation.

If you're unfamiliar with JavaScript's DOM manipulation methods, I consider the [quirksmode intro](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) to be approachable and informative.

Comment: the thing is I want to strip the tags but keep any text content that resides in these tags. I am experienced with jQuery but can see how to do this easily...

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
<?php
$new_content = strip_tags($content, '<a><br>');
```

This would allow all `br` and all `a`-elements. Unforutantely in this function you don't have the possibility to allow/disallow element-properties like your `class="user"`. This functions allways allows/disallows the specified elements with *all* properties.

Comment: This is a javscript issue not php. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the tags :(